# What will happen if I delete the Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-games

What will happen if I delete and re-install the Google Play Services?

Will all my game data be deleted too?

Comment: First, to restrict the conjunctive: is your device rooted? If not, it's a very theoretical question as you won't be able to delete the Play Services app.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play services is required to access features from Google, such as downloading apps from Google Play and accessing Google Play Games for achievements. If you are reinstalling Google Play Services, your game data will not be harmed as they are either synced onto cloud or is stored locally and separate from Google. However, reinstalling does not really help. Is battery drain the issue? You can try deleting app data, which is similar to reinstalling. Freezing it with Lucky Patcher may also solve some of your problems.